# List of apps on Google Play ever installed by me on any Android phone

Tags: applications, google-play-store, google-play-services, android-12

I am running Android 12 on a Realme 8 5G Android smartphone.

I am wondering about the Google Play app that came preinstalled.

There used to be a place on my older phone in this app where I could see all apps I ever installed from Google Play, including paid apps and free apps.

However, now I just see a list of installed apps there and must remember to remember what apps I used to use on my older phone (which broke while this one was being used by another user, an now I'm the user of this phone and my username appears in the Google Play app).

Thank you for your feedback and help.

Answer (score 2):

The recent Google Play App don't seem to be able to show the complete list of apps, but the Google Play web site still does:

Visit `https://play.google.com/apps` to get a list of all your apps had have or had installed.

The link above is intentionally not clickable for the reason that if you click it in a web browser on Android you will be redirected to the start activity the Google Play Store App (which does not show the app list.
Instead you have to manually enter `play.google.com/apps` into the address bar e.g. of Chrome for Android. In my test when manually entered I was not redirected to Play Store App.

Comment: My experience is that if you've installed many items via the Google Play Store, you need to keep clicking/scrolling to show them, perhaps hundreds of times.  Does this match your experience?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Indeed it requires a little effort to get the full list of apps as the list is loaded incrementally and some times even require clicking a button. For citizens of the EU may be the full GDPR data export is an easier way as it also should include the full list of apps you have or had installed (not checked how complicated it is to find the list in the data export): https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190?hl=en